# Pagination with Mysql and PHP Help

Tags: php, loops, pagination

I am trying to create a pagination with just next and previous links instead of 1,2,3..etc.

So I have say item 1,2,3,4,5 in the database and each item is on one page.

If I am on item 2 page I would like a previous link for item 1 page and a next link for item 3 page...etc

So far I got up to retrieving all the items in the database and created a loop to spit out all the URL in each item.  But I don't quite know the best way to strip off all the items except the adjacent items.  This is the loop I have so far.

foreach ($item_url as $url) :
echo $url['url'];
endforeach;

This spits out all URL...But how do i proceed to list only the adjacent items and not count the current item I am on...I tried using next($url); to move the pointer if it matches the current item but it didn't work...

Thanks, guys!

Comment: http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Link-Farm-Code/Pagination/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat resource for paging tabular data without the headache of writing your own code or the need for any PHP at all.  Throw all the results into a table (or output them via JSON if you are so inclined)  Now, apply the [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) plugin to the table id and tell it to do pagination.  Voila, instant pagination, no brain damage required.